# I didn't understand the below from sets and functions algebra caltech pdf. The highlight is my problem. What does it mean and why does say X=0?

Tags: rational-functions

I am not English speaking and also highlight is yellow in solution…

[image]

> The graph in the fogure shows an even function $f(x) = \dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are rational quadratic polynomials. Give possible formulas for $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

[image]

Comment: It is better to insert the image rather than a link to the image, as well as providing the relevant parts of the text, the statement and the beginning of the proof, rather than two links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first picture we are meant to see that $f(0)=0$, and also that the $x$-axis is a tangent, so that $f'(0)=0$. That's what a "second-order zero" means.  That means the same is true for $p(x)$, so that $x^2$ must divide $p(x)$.

The constant $\chi$ can't be $0$ or else an $x$ on the denominator would cancel out one of the $x$s on top, and leave us with just a simple zero, not a second-order one.

Comment: It means degree of p is 2 (or x^2 is not zero), am i right about second order zero?the figure shows it is second order zero????



Thanks!

Comment: No, the solution assumes the degree of $p$ is $2$. Looking at the graph of $f$ one can "see" that it passes thro $0$ and is flat there, so that $x^2$ must divide $p$.

Comment: d(P(x)) is 0 is second order zero???derivative of p... ?? what is 1st order zero or 3rd for example?

Comment: If $F(x)=(x-a)^n G(x)$ with $G(a)\not=0$ then $F$ has a zero of order $n$ at the point $a$.